# jQuery UI dialog TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

My UI dialogs works from time to time but usually it throws this error :

```
 TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
```

I do not know why is this happening. This is my .*js* code :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#dialog_box_hypo").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,  
    width:'auto',
});
$("#dialog_box_kk").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,  
    width:'auto',
});
$("#hypo_u_stats").click(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.0.200/dev/vub/hypo_user_stats.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned  
        success: function(response){
            $("#dialog_box_hypo").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,  
                width:'auto',
            });
            $('#dialog_box_hypo').html(response);
            $("#dialog_box_hypo").dialog( "open" );
        }
});
});
$("#kk_u_stats").click(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.0.200/dev/vub/kk_user_stats.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned  
        success: function(response){
            $("#dialog_box_kk").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,  
                width:'auto',
            });
            $('#dialog_box_kk').html(response);
            $("#dialog_box_kk").dialog( "open" );
        }
});
});
});
```

Maybe it is caused by ajax call? This is my .html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog_box_hypo" title="Operátori HYPO"></div>
<div id="dialog_box_kk" title="Operátori KK"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anybody any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the conditions that you get this error? Is there any conflicting code in `js/custom.js`. I do not see `$("#hypo_u_stats")` or `$("#kk_u_stats")` in your HTML. Please edit your post and clarify the issue further.

Comment: Unable to replicate the issue. Tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/00fdnb7o/